# Dealing with different units and indexes in regressions

Tags: regression, correlation, data-transformation, stata, growth-model

In my time series model, my dependent variable is a growth measure in percentage. However, one of my independent variables is an index that ranges from -2.5 to 2.5 - and is producing some extreme coefficients.

An example using corruption (`cce`) is this:

[image]

It doesn't seem reasonable that an extra unit of corruption leads to 49% decrease in growth since the index ranges from -2.5 to 2.5.

Is there any way to transform such a variable to get slightly smoother / easier coefficients to deal with?

Comment: Why you consider this a weird result? Is it common to observe this variability in this so called corruption index (e.g. a one unit increase) ?. Also, if you consider the p-value, this coefficient isn't significant to start with, so you couldn't be drawing conclusion from these results.

Comment: This was just one country, and there were others that did face significance. The variability is not usually observed to that extremes. It would be much more common to see a shift from something like 1.5 to 1.6/1.7. Not a shift from 1.5 to 2.5. This is why my coefficients seem hard to interpret

Answer (score 2):

Look at the high p-value (0.083 > 0.05) and the large confidence interval (crossing the zero): your explanatory variable is not significant.

Comment: Since this is not an answer, I believe it should be a comment,

Comment: @LucasFarias I'm not sure. It is brief but says what is to be said. Notice that the question doesn't give much details as well, so there is not more that we could add.